# Spring Transaction Hibernate @Transaction annotation not working with @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

Spring Transaction Hibernate `@Transaction` annotation is not working with `@Autowired` correctly. If I create the ``` Dao`` element by ```xml(UserDao2 userDao2)`,

the transactional anotation in the Service class is working, if its by `@Repository` annotation in the Dao class when tries to getCurrentSesion, says:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97) ~[spring-orm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:993) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.11.Final.jar:4.2.11.Final]
```

It appears that is not linking well the `@Transactional` annotation with the session factory

Library versions:

```
<jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
<spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
<hibernate.version>4.2.11.Final</hibernate.version>
```

**spring-database.xml**

```
<context:annotation-config />

 <jee:jndi-lookup id="datasourcenn" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/nn_datasource" /> 

    <bean id="sesionHibernate"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasourcenn"/>

        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.web.entity"/>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</prop>            
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>

                        <!-- nuevas properties de configuración -->
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>

                <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.provider">cglib</prop>                                    
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>    

    <bean id="us" class="com.web.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sesionHibernate" ref="sesionHibernate" />
    </bean>
    <!--  -->
    <bean id="userDao2" class="com.web.dao.UserDao2Impl">
        <property name="sesionHibernate" ref="sesionHibernate" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="com.web.service.UsuarioServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="us" />
    </bean> 
    <!--
    proxy-target-class="true"  mode="aspectj" 
    -->

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sesionHibernate"></property>

    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

**UserDao2** (I remove @Repository if I create it by xml)

```
@Repository
public class UserDao2Impl implements UserDao2 {
  private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDao2Impl.class);

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("sesionHibernate")
  private SessionFactory sesionHibernate;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public Usuario findByUserName(String username) {
    try {
      log.info("findByUserName" + sesionHibernate);

      List<Usuario> users = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
      System.out.println(sesionHibernate+"\n----------");

      users = sesionHibernate.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Usuario where nombre=?").setParameter(0, username).list();
      // users = sesionHibernate.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Usuario
      // where nombre=?").setParameter(0, username).list();

      if (users.size() > 0) {
        return users.get(0);
      } else {
        return null;
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("findByUserName ", e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

**Usuario2ServiceImpl** If have the service with @Transacional

```
@Service 
@Transactional
public class Usuario2ServiceImpl implements Usuario2Service {
  private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Usuario2ServiceImpl.class);

  //Qualifier("userDaoImpl")
  @Autowired
  private UserDao2 userDao2;       

  @Override
  public com.web.entity.Usuario getUsuariodetalles(final String nombreUsuario) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    log.info("getUsuariodetalles - 1");
    System.out.println("ssss"+userDao2);
    com.web.entity.Usuario usuario = userDao2.findByUserName(nombreUsuario);    

    log.info("getUsuariodetalles - 2");
    return usuario;   
  }
```

Comment: You have both `@Service` and `<bean>`.

Comment: No, the bean is for another class  UsuarioServiceImpl, the @Service is for UsuarioService2Impl

Comment: Let me guess yu have a `ContextLoaderLIstener` which loads the `spring-database.xml` and you have a `DispatcherServlet` which loads something else and which contains a `<context:component-scan />`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, i add to mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, mvc:interceptors configuration to open session with org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor. Just need to define the sessionFactory in the properties.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd    
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        ">
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web" />

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
            <bean name="OpenSessionInViewInterceptorCom" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
                <property name="sessionFactory">
                    <ref bean ="sesionHibernate" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting @Transactional annotation at service layer method, you have placed it on class. I think it should work.

Comment: I tried to put @Transactional on Interface of the service, on the function that is called, in the interface on the functio, everywhere, and i  still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in Tomcat the issue by putting in the `spring-database.xml` the next line:

```
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="autodetect"/>
```

**But it doesn't work in JBoss**, which is where i need to deploy the final version. Other solution?

In Jboss i need to create both things in the xml(Service and Dao), keeping the transactional annotatations. But i doesn't work if create them(dao & service) with @Repository or @Service.